# Algrotihm to rank records based on multiple criteria

Tags: sorting, ranking

This is general "algorithmic" question rather than a programming one.

Assume we have a table of records in the following form:

```
S/N   Cost   Profit  Review   
 1      5      9      4
 2     10      6      5
 3      8     11      6
 4     12      5      9
```

and we want to somehow sort and rank these records according to multiple criteria (attributes); for example cost and profit.

Is there any known process or algorithm that can help in doing so?

I know this is a multi-objective problem but I'm trying to find out if there is an alternative in sorting records in a table with multiple attributes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post maths questions on the Maths stack exchange.

Comment: @NewWorld it's an algorithmic question. Thus, I think it's suitable here as well. Thanks.

Comment: My mistake; this question is more suited to the Computer Science stack exchange than SO.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! In your problem you want to sort depending on one or more than one attribute. I am assuming here that an attribute has more value than another attribute, so for example if you order by `cost` at first, and you end up with three items with same `cost` you fall into sorting depending on another less-valued attribute: `profit` for example.

**The Algorithm:**

1. Sort with an efficient sorting algorithm - say: [quickSort](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/quick-sort)
2. Extract duplicates (if any) then sort them using the other (*less-valued*) attribute
3. Combine both arrays <- this depends how do you want the final sort to be.
4. print

This algorithm should be total of `O(2nLogn) => O(nLogn)`

[image]

Comment: @AK, thanks a lot for your suggestion. This is one possible workaround for the problem. However, are you aware of any technique/approach than can be used to rank records by applying multiple criteria simultaneously?

Comment: You can't really order a thing based on two cafeterias in the same time even as a human, there is a criteria that will be worth more than the other at some point.. 

Another solution would be merging these two cafeterias into one say: `total-criteria = 90% criteria-1 + 10% criteria-2` then sort based on `total-criteria`

Comment: @AK, I agree that this is a possible solution to this issue. Well, the problem in this instance is that if you want to select a record that satisfies these criteria and minimises a utility function, then you can't avoid brute force, I'm afraid. This is why I'm trying to figure out whether there is an alternative way of doing it.